# What can I do with UFO in openttd?

Tags: openttd

I play often in multiplayer mode in openttd. 

The UFO is really annoying. How do you deal with it?

Comment: I feel like there isn't a way to deal with it. You just have to suck up the damage and repair what it broke after it leaves. But I'm not 100% on that

Answer (score 2):

If you are talking about the UFOs that destroy train tracks, then the best way, in the original TTD, to survive it was to park a train in the area that it landed in.  The UFO would destroy land around the train, but wouldn't destroy the track where the train was parked.

I'd suggest testing this with a non-critical train as I'm not sure if this is the same in OpenTTD!

Answer (score 1):

The UFO is a type of Disaster, which can be turned off in the Advanced Settings menu (as of version 1.3) under Economy. To do this in multiplayer would probably require the intervention of the administrator or host of the game.

[image]

Otherwise, if you're not the admin or don't want to turn off all disasters, the only choice you have is to suck it up and rebuild after it is destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, park the train exactly where the UFO is at. Wait awhile and a fighter jet flies past to destroy the UFO. The train stays alive but surrounding tracks will be destroyed. You have no control over the jet anyhow. Saw it as it happened in my scenario game.